# I am getting duplicate data on swipe more in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to fetch paginated data in my flutter app from my website using REST API.

I have integrated pagination and now it is started working.

But the problem is that on loading more data, I am getting duplicate data instead of getting new data.

I think I am doing something wrong to increment the page no. in the `_getAllNews()` method

Here is my complete code, and I think I am doing very small mistake in this.

```
class Tedd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeddState createState() => _TeddState();
}

class _TeddState extends State<Tedd> {
  List<NewsModel> _newsList = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  int currentPage = 1;
  bool hasReachedEnd = false;
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  _getAllNews(page) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var articles = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://pkbhai.com/myprojects/kids-stories/api/all-stories?page=${page}"));
    var result = json.decode(articles.body);
    print(result);
    result['data'].forEach((data) {
      var news = NewsModel();
      news.id = data["id"];
      news.articleTitle = data["name"];
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _newsList.add(news);
          isLoading = false;
          currentPage = currentPage++;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  void handleNext() {
    scrollController.addListener(() async {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
          scrollController.position.pixels) {
        _getAllNews(currentPage);
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _getAllNews(currentPage);
    handleNext();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        itemCount: _newsList.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _newsList.length) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return Container(
              height: 150, child: Text(_newsList[index].articleTitle!));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `print(results)` prints ? You can also `print(data);` inside forEach to make sure the error doesn't come from the backend. 
If it show some duplicates, it's a backend error, it can be a simple error in order of execution the query to paginate. For example skip -> sort -> limit might give duplicate. You have to sort first, then skip (to get to page x), then limit (to get the y elements from page x) .

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code, if you said if keep repeating data, check your your backend implementation of pagination. By the way why cant to controller the pagination in client sdy...

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga here is my backend api
 https://pkbhai.com/myprojects/kids-stories/api/all-stories

Comment: @Fourchette here is my api https://pkbhai.com/myprojects/kids-stories/api/all-stories

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga please help me to get it  worked

Comment: @PramodYadav I am off system, that will later.

Answer (score 0):

i have check the api, now the problem of the repeated data is coming from the api url.

after check the api and test base on this 3 parameter,

```
 current_page= 1,
from=1,
last_page=3,
```

but is not working...

solution:
contact the developer of the api and check the api or recreate another working pagination url for you to make request